# What is the objective of philosophy according to the late Wittgenstein?

Tags: metaphilosophy, wittgenstein

Wittgenstein early metaphilosophy in the *TLP* basically gives philosophy the role of "riddler solver", that is, a discipline whose main task is to study language in order to clarify the meaning of propositions, or to show that a proposition clearly lacks meaning.

How does this change in the *Philosophical Investigation*? What is the objective of philosophy according to the late Wittgenstein?

Comment: Do you want answers restricted to the *Philosophical Investigations* or do you want people delving into the various notebooks?

Comment: Isn't this no more than an aspect of the Socratic attitude in Platos dialogues; say for example when Socrates questions Cephalus in *The Republic* as to what, then exactly constitutes justice; or when Socrates questions *Ion* in his eponymous dialogue as to what constitutes the skill of a *rhapsode* (a singer); how then does one distinguish between this attitude and that of late Wittegenstein?

Comment: @virmaior Any comment on the change in Wittgenstein's metaphilosophy will be appreciated. I mentioned the Philosophical Investigation because it is the Tractatus and Philosophical Investigations because they are the most well-known representatives of the early and late Wittgenstein respectively,

Comment: As far as I understood from better informed people, he completely rejected the project of any objective philosophy in his later years, very much like Husserl, who had a try of it of his own in his early years.

Comment: His famous observation on the "bewitchment of language" is given below. I believe he did regard philosophy as having a kind of medicinal or healing function, except that "philosophy" is also the disease. He advised his students to go work in a factory and he said that the aim of philosophy was to "leave life as it found it." Not sure I'm quoting correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several remarks in the Philosophical Investigations in which Wittgenstein comments on the "business" of philosophy:

> It was correct that our considerations must not be scientific ones.
>   The feeling ‘that it is possible, contrary to our preconceived ideas, to
>   think this or that’ — whatever that may mean — could be of no interest to us. (The pneumatic conception of thinking.) And we may not
>   advance any kind of theory. There must not be anything hypothetical
>   in our considerations. All explanation must disappear, and description
>   alone must take its place. And this description gets its light — that is
>   to say, its purpose — from the philosophical problems. These are, of
>   course, not empirical problems; but they are solved through an insight
>   into the workings of our language, and that in such a way that these
>   workings are recognized — despite an urge to misunderstand them. The
>   problems are solved, not by coming up with new discoveries, but by
>   assembling what we have long been familiar with. Philosophy is a struggle against the bewitchment of our understanding by the resources of
>   our language. (§109)

And from §122 to §129:

> It is not the business of philosophy to resolve a contradiction by
>   means of a mathematical or logico-mathematical discovery, but to render surveyable the state of mathematics that troubles us — the state of
>   affairs before the contradiction is resolved. (§125)
>
> Philosophy just puts everything before us, and neither explains nor
>   deduces anything. — Since everything lies open to view, there is nothing to explain. For whatever may be hidden is of no interest to us. (§126)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the objective of philosophy according to the late
>   Wittgenstein?

The objective of philosophy according to the later Wittgenstein is both to make us aware of the temptation of any a-priori generalization and to show how to overcome it.

(The **rejection**, which marks the thansition from early to later Wittgenstein is, more generally, addressed to every kind of **dogmatism** in philosophy and the Philosophical Investigations can be seen as the culmination of all the consequences of this rejection).

The rejecting of any a-priori generalization is also the **rejection of the tractarian approach**, which did consist in reducing the sphere of the sayable to meaningful declarative sentences which are all of equal value, by virtue of a general form of truth-function ([p-, ξ-, N(ξ-)]), therefore every meaningful sentence is, abstractly and dogmatically, no more than the result of successive application of a formula consisting on a formal operation and one propositional variable (see *TLP* 6 and following comment).

So, while the Tractatus does construct a systematic edifice which relies on strict formal logic, on the other hands the Philosophical Investigations points out the therapeutic non-dogmatic nature of philosophy, verily instructing philosophers in the way of therapy. Consequently, according to this new viewpoint, a philosophical problem has the form: "I don't know my way about" (*PI* 123), and hence the aim of philosophy is "to show the fly the way out of the fly-bottle" (*PI* 309)

(source: see in particular the paragraph 3.7. *The Nature of Philosophy* [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/%E2%81%A0entries/%E2%81%A0wittgenstein/%E2%81%A0))